# XQUERY Tumbling window

Tags: xquery

```
for tumbling window $w in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)
    start at $s when fn:true()
    only end at $e when $e - $s eq 2
return <window>{ $w }</window>
```

Result of the above query:

```
<window>2 4 6</window>
<window>8 10 12</window>
```

Can someone explain why is it <2 4 6>, <8 10 12> ? Why only 3 values <2 4 6>, <8 10 12>, and how is it working to get 2 4 6, or 8 10 12 ?

Answer (score 4):

The example

```
for tumbling window $w in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)
    start at $s when fn:true()
    only end at $e when $e - $s eq 2
return <window>{ $w }</window>
```

seems to be taken directly from the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-tumbling-windows and that has some good explanation of the result:

> Windows are created by iterating over the items in the binding
>   sequence, in order, identifying the start item and the end item of
>   each window by evaluating the WindowStartCondition and the
>   WindowEndCondition. Each of these conditions is satisfied if the
>   effective boolean value of the expression following the when keyword
>   is true. The start item of the window is an item that satisfies the
>   WindowStartCondition (see 3.10.4.1 Tumbling Windows and 3.10.4.2
>   Sliding Windows for a more complete explanation.) The end item of the
>   window is the first item in the binding sequence, beginning with the
>   start item, that satisfies the WindowEndCondition (again, see 3.10.4.1
>   Tumbling Windows and 3.10.4.2 Sliding Windows for more details.) Each
>   window contains its start item, its end item, and all items that occur
>   between them in the binding sequence.
>
> If the window type is tumbling, then windows never overlap. The search
>   for the start of the first window begins at the beginning of the
>   binding sequence. After each window is generated, the search for the
>   start of the next window begins with the item in the binding sequence
>   that occurs after the ending item of the last generated window. Thus,
>   no item that occurs in one window can occur in another window drawn
>   from the same binding sequence (unless the sequence contains the same
>   item more than once).

So with the binding sequence being `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14` the variables defined using `start at $s` and `only end at $e` are positional:

> Start-item-position: (Optional) Bound to the ordinal position of the
>   first window item in the binding sequence. Start-item-position is a
>   positional variable; hence, its type is xs:integer End-item-position:
>   (Optional) Bound to the ordinal position of the last window item in
>   the binding sequence. End-item-position is a positional variable;
>   hence, its type is xs:integer

and for the first item `2` and the third item `6` the positional values `3 - 1` are `2` so the first window contains `2, 4, 6`, then the search for a new window starts with `8` at position `4` and ends with `12` at position `6` as `6 - 4` is also `2`.